# Why does canned food expire soon once the can is opened?

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime

Canned food can maintain 1+ year in good state. However, when you open the can, the countdown starts.

I read it happens because microorganism from the outside reach the inside of the can.

My question is: Is it possible to keep food inside the just opened can free of microorganisms? Maybe moving immediately to an airtight container and take out the needed amount with a cleaned spoon? (If a cleaned spoon still contains microorganism --- why clean it in the first place?)

Comment: Clean spoon does not have food to feed the microorganism.

Comment: You will notice that stuff in an airtight container *does* have less propensity of spoiling catastrophically and quickly if only touched with clean utensils - but unsealing the can still degrades the content from "sterile/pasteurized" to "very damn clean"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

When you can something, the temperature and pressure kill bacteria and micro-organisms.

Once its exposed to air, you're exposing it to bacteria and micro-organisms. Despite you thinking the spoon is clean, it still has some bacteria and micro-organisms on it which will get into the food. And your "airtight" container is likely not nearly as airtight as a can.